# I want to migrate paperclip gem to active_storage Ruby on Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rails-activestorage

...like this: [paperclip2active_storage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/MIGRATING.md)

**Update** be sure to watch the linked video presentation as the text document does not present all the quirks!

so I installed and configured rails 7 and gem 'mini_magick'. Now I suppose the referenced script will update all my models, views and controllers:

but, when I run it I get error like this:

```
leder@home-ryzen-desktop:~/Git/gmr_production_heroku$ ruby migration.rb 
migration.rb:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)
```

`migration.rb` as described in the referenced link!

How do I do migrate my RoR App?

---

I have removed `development` from `database.yml` and added to `storage.yml`:

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

amazon:
...
```

Now I get this error:

```
leder@home-ryzen-desktop:~/Git/gmr_production_heroku$ bundle exec rake db:create
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: The `development` database is not configured for the `development` environment.

  Available database configurations are:

  production
/home/leder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/leder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How do I migrate this to `active_storage`?

---

Follow up question can be found here: [Part2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67690478/i-want-to-migrate-paperclip-gem-to-active-storage-ruby-on-rails-7-part2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the migration in the context of Rails. So `ruby migration.rb` won't work.

You need to generate a migration with `bin/rails g migration <migration_name>`.

Then once you copy the code into the migration, run `bin/rails db:migrate`.

P.S. Rails 7 hasn't been released yet. So moving to Rails 7 might be premature since it may still have bugs and many gems may not support it fully

Comment: OK: migration created and run, db configured... why do I get a db error now:

```Showing /home/leder/Git/gmr_production_heroku/app/views/articles/index.html.erb where line #9 raised:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: articles
Extracted source (around line #9):

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <table border="3" frame="void" rules="groups">
```

Comment: You seem to be using an SQLite database on Heroku. That is not advised since SQLite is a file system database and there is no guarantee such a DB will persist. You need to use a DB like PostgreSQL or MySQL instead