# I want to migrate paperclip gem to active_storage Ruby on Rails 7, Part2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rails-activestorage

I follow  [paperclip2active_storage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/MIGRATING.md). My `database.yml` defines a sqlite DB for environment `development` that is no longer needed, b/c `acitve_storage` uses Disk storage as follows:

`database.yml`

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: w29ifufy55ljjmzq.cbetxkdyhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  database: llpdn9i88kz3y837
  pool: 5
  ...
```

`development.rb`

```
# Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

---

I have removed `development` from `database.yml` and added to `storage.yml`:

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

amazon:
...
```

Now I get this error:

```
leder@home-ryzen-desktop:~/Git/gmr_production_heroku$ bundle exec rake db:create
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: The `development` database is not configured for the `development` environment.

  Available database configurations are:

  production
/home/leder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/leder/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How do I migrate this to `active_storage`? I want to configure local Disk access for environment `development.rb` and mysql2 DB for environment `production.rb`?! But `database.yml` and `storage.yml` do not go together well!

---

Comment: The error is about your database in general and has nothing to do with ActiveStorage. I have no idea where you are going with "My database.yml defines a sqlite DB for environment development that is no longer needed...". ActiveRecord still needs somewhere to store your records including the ActiveStorage tables!

Comment: ActiveStorage stores the images and files themselves on disk, the references to them, and all lookup from the db is done with ActiveRecord however, you still need a db if you want to use ActiveStorage.

Comment: OK: I now did create migrations for `CreateArticles` and `CreateComments`, but running the `db:migrate` it does not recognize the `t.has_one_attached : attachment`:

```NoMethodError: undefined method `has_one_attached' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3::TableDefinition:0x000055be9a46cce8 @conn=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAda```